# QGIS Graphical Modeler - Export as Script Algorithm - Run Issue

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I recently posted a question to this site about a model I am building using the QGIS Model Designer for a project of mine. This site has been a great community for help and the model is now working as I had intended. However, I would now like to export this model as a Python script to add some additional functionality that I do not believe is possible in the GUI Model Designer.

I have exported the model as a script using the "Export as Script Algorithm". When I run the script, it brings up the same window for inputs, but when I then hit run from there it only gets to about 20% completion before hanging up and not progressing any further. QGIS stops responding and then, after some time, it crashes my machine.

See the model here:

[image: QGIS Model]

This is the scrpt as produced by the export as script algorithm:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterNumber
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterDefinition
from qgis.core import QgsExpression
import processing

class WtgLayoutTool(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource('windfarmboundary', 'Wind Farm Boundary', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('prevailingwinddirection', 'Prevailing Wind Direction ( ° )', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, minValue=0, maxValue=360, defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('wtgrotordiameter', 'WTG Rotor Diameter ( m )', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, minValue=0, maxValue=500, defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('prevailingrdspacing', 'Prevailing RD Spacing', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double, minValue=0, maxValue=100, defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('perpendicularrdspacing', 'Perpendicular RD Spacing', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double, minValue=0, maxValue=100, defaultValue=None))
    param = QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('exclusionzones', 'Exclusion Zones', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None)
    param.setFlags(param.flags() | QgsProcessingParameterDefinition.FlagAdvanced)
    self.addParameter(param)
    param = QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('bathymetry', 'Bathymetry', optional=True, defaultValue=None)
    param.setFlags(param.flags() | QgsProcessingParameterDefinition.FlagAdvanced)
    self.addParameter(param)
    param = QgsProcessingParameterNumber('maximumwaterdepthxm', 'Maximum Water Depth ( -Xm )', optional=True, type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, minValue=-1000, maxValue=0, defaultValue=None)
    param.setFlags(param.flags() | QgsProcessingParameterDefinition.FlagAdvanced)
    self.addParameter(param)
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('WtgLayoutReduced', 'WTG Layout (Reduced)', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('WtgLayoutBasic', 'WTG Layout (Basic)', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue='TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
    # overall progress through the model
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(10, model_feedback)
    results = {}
    outputs = {}

    # Wind Farm Buffer
    alg_params = {
        'DISSOLVE': False,
        'DISTANCE': 5000,
        'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,  # Round
        'INPUT': parameters['windfarmboundary'],
        'JOIN_STYLE': 0,  # Round
        'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
        'SEGMENTS': 5,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['WindFarmBuffer'] = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Initial Points Grid
    alg_params = {
        'CRS': 'ProjectCrs',
        'EXTENT': outputs['WindFarmBuffer']['OUTPUT'],
        'HOVERLAY': 0,
        'HSPACING': QgsExpression('@wtgrotordiameter * @perpendicularrdspacing').evaluate(),
        'TYPE': 0,  # Point
        'VOVERLAY': 0,
        'VSPACING': QgsExpression(' @wtgrotordiameter * @prevailingrdspacing ').evaluate(),
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['InitialPointsGrid'] = processing.run('native:creategrid', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Dissolve to Single Feature
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD': [''],
        'INPUT': outputs['InitialPointsGrid']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['DissolveToSingleFeature'] = processing.run('native:dissolve', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Rotate Points Grid
    alg_params = {
        'ANCHOR': None,
        'ANGLE': QgsExpression(' @prevailingwinddirection +(atan( @perpendicularrdspacing / @prevailingrdspacing )*57.2957795130823)').evaluate(),
        'INPUT': outputs['DissolveToSingleFeature']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['RotatePointsGrid'] = processing.run('native:rotatefeatures', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Clip Points Grid to Wind Farm Boundary
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': outputs['RotatePointsGrid']['OUTPUT'],
        'OVERLAY': parameters['windfarmboundary'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['ClipPointsGridToWindFarmBoundary'] = processing.run('native:clip', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Split Points Grid into Individual Features #1
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': outputs['ClipPointsGridToWindFarmBoundary']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': parameters['WtgLayoutBasic']
    }
    outputs['SplitPointsGridIntoIndividualFeatures1'] = processing.run('native:multiparttosingleparts', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['WtgLayoutBasic'] = outputs['SplitPointsGridIntoIndividualFeatures1']['OUTPUT']

    feedback.setCurrentStep(6)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Clip Points Grid Using Exclusion Zones
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': outputs['ClipPointsGridToWindFarmBoundary']['OUTPUT'],
        'OVERLAY': parameters['exclusionzones'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['ClipPointsGridUsingExclusionZones'] = processing.run('native:difference', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(7)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Split Points Grid into Individual Features #2
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': outputs['ClipPointsGridUsingExclusionZones']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['SplitPointsGridIntoIndividualFeatures2'] = processing.run('native:multiparttosingleparts', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(8)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Sample Bathymetry
    alg_params = {
        'COLUMN_PREFIX': 'Water Depth (m)',
        'INPUT': outputs['SplitPointsGridIntoIndividualFeatures2']['OUTPUT'],
        'RASTERCOPY': parameters['bathymetry'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['SampleBathymetry'] = processing.run('native:rastersampling', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(9)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Extract by expression
    alg_params = {
        'EXPRESSION': '"Water Depth (m)1">= @maximumwaterdepthxm ',
        'INPUT': outputs['SampleBathymetry']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': parameters['WtgLayoutReduced']
    }
    outputs['ExtractByExpression'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['WtgLayoutReduced'] = outputs['ExtractByExpression']['OUTPUT']
    return results

def name(self):
    return 'WTG Layout Tool'

def displayName(self):
    return 'WTG Layout Tool'

def group(self):
    return 'WTG Layout Tools'

def groupId(self):
    return 'WTG Layout Tools'

def createInstance(self):
    return WtgLayoutTool()
```